# How to tell if loadUrl() was called DIRECTLY or as a result of touching a link?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

In a WebView-derived class I override loadUrl():

```
  @Override
  public void loadUrl(String url) {
    super.loadUrl(url);
  }
```

Inside this overriden loadUrl(), I want to know whether it was called as a result of the user touching a link (inside the same WebView), or was actually called directly somewhere in my program (either directly by me, or indirectly as a result of some Javascript processing etc.).

I was initially thinking of distinguishing between the two by setting a flag in an `OnTouchListener()`:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      // set flag !!!
  }
  return false;
}
```

and resetting it in loadUrl(), *after* checking its value.

The problem with this "solution" is that in the aforementioned onTouch() implementation, *any* touch sets the flag, so a false scenario like this is possible:

1. The user touches the screen (but not a link!)
2. onTouch sets the flag.
3. My program calls loadUrl() directly.
4. loadUrl() checks the flag and thinks that it was called as result of a touch.

So obviously the above onTouch() handling is too simplistic and doesn't work.

Any idea how to implement code that actually knows how to tell between a touch-triggered loadUrl() and a **non**-touch-triggered loadUrl()?

**Update:** I checked the stack trace suggestion below, and this is the stack trace at loadUrl() when it is invoked via touch:

```
com.utubefan.MyWebView.loadUrl(MyWebView.java:365)
com.utubefan.MyWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(MyWebViewClient.java:123)
android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:216)
android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:323)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am not sure that I can identify an explicit touch event there, but the following looks promising (they don't appear on a non-touch loadUrl):

```
android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:216)
android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:323)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a proper way to do what you're asking but I can think of a way that will probably work. In your loadUrl() override, you can query your calling stack and see what routine called into you. Your caller will be one location for a touch leading to you, and anything else for having been called programatically.

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=78 contains code showing how to determine your stack trace from a throwable (which you would create in your loadUrl() method).

Comment: That's a wonderful idea. Does this assume that the "stack distance" from a touch even is always the same? Certainly worth trying (unless there is a more direct WebView-specific existing mechanism).

Comment: I would not think the stack path would change, since it's the same routine calling into loadUrl(), directly or indirectly. The risk is that different versions of the Android framework have a different calling signature -- low risk but worth researching using emulators of various versions if you need the broad coverage.

Comment: See my update above. `uiOverrideUrlLoading` looks promising, but now that you pointed out the possibility of different Android versions, this looks scary. There are so many Android versions and flavors out there...